# Resubmitting DMA Engine transactions

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, dma

I'm writing a custom high-speed Linux SPI driver for an embedded SoC. To send data to the SPI peripheral (`DMA_MEM_TO_DEV`) I'm the Linux DMA Engine API.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dmaengine/client.txt

Based on the documentation, the steps for setting up and executing a DMA transaction are:

1. Allocate a DMA slave channel : `dma_request_channel`
2. Set slave and controller specific parameters : `dmaengine_slave_config`
3. Get a descriptor for tranesaction : `dmaengine_prep_slave_single`
4. Submit the transaction : `dmaengine_submit`
5. Issue pending requests and wait for callback notification : `dma_async_issue_pending`

I have this working for single DMA transactions. But I need to send multiple DMA transactions from the same memory location (`dma_addr_t buf`) of the same size (`size_t len`) based on some hardware flow control (GPIOs).

For starters, I tried to redo step 1-5 for every DMA transaction. So every time the flow control GPIO IRQ triggers, I reallocate a DMA slave channel, re-set the slave and controller specific parameters, ...

This seems to work too, but I am not sure if it's the most efficient way.

I am wondering if I can just re-submit the transaction again (`dmaengine_submit`) and issue again (`dma_async_issue_pending`)? Would this be more efficient?

I can't seem to find any information on how to resubmit the exact same DMA request anywhere in the kernel documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 1 and 2 need not be repeated. Steps 3 to 5 can be repeated for multiple transactions. For example, see the patch [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=90ba37033cb94207e97c4ced9be575770438213b). ***dspi_dma_xfer*** function can call ***dspi_next_xfer_dma_submit*** multiple times and steps 3 to 5 are redone. Since you want the ***dma_addr_t buf*** to be the same, as far as I understand this is what you want.

Comment: Yup. Exactly what I wanted to confirm. Thanks! Also thanks for linking to an example from the kernel which I can follow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least re-init the memory source address, destination address, and length registers as they will change over the course of the DMA transaction. I think it would be just as fast to just redo everything each time - its not very much to setup and thus the time spent is minuscule.

Comment: Indeed. But ideally, these would be done by the DMA Engine implementation. I'm just not sure if the `dma_desc` that returned from the `dmaengine_prep_slave_single` can be reused.